# How to implement sed range pattern command on groovy script

Tags: groovy, sed

I'm struggling to implement the sed range pattern command on groovy script.

This is how I'm attempting to implement the command in groovy script:

```
 def range = sed -n -e /Word A/,/Word D/ p
 def result = cat sample.txt | range.execute()
```

This is the content of the sample.txt file:

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word E
Word F
```

This is the output I want:

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
```

Now, the error that is returned to me when I run it is:

```
sed: unmatched '/'
```

I believe the reason why I'm getting this error is because in the actual sed command, I need to somehow group the range pattern altogether because I feel and in fact I've tested it, the sed command only applies to the first range, i.e. "WORD A" and then it reads the next "/" as a literal character rather than a character that encapsulates the next pattern which is WORD D.

I've tried to use single quotes and double quotes but upon running my script, I get an error saying either: sed unmatched "'" or sed unknown command.

Ultimately, I need to somehow say the following in groovy script:

```
sed -n -e (/Word A/,/Word D/ p)
```

Can someone please help resolve this issue as it's taken me two days to work this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to produce `"Word"` followed by letters in a range?

Comment: Crossposting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/470688/74329

Comment: @ernest_k, im not quite sure what you mean. I want to return the list of words between Word A and Word D

Comment: Well, if all you want is generate that, then you can use `('A'..'D').collect{"Word $it"}.join("\n")`, and then save the result to a file...

Comment: is collect a java method? And what is $it?

Comment: You state you get an error, but the code you posted there is invalid groovy.  Please share the real code.  Guessing from the error message: you are using a String to keep the command - and this will not work.  Always use an array: `["sed", "-n", "-e", "s/word a/word b", ...].execute()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along those lines :

```
def isBlockStart =  { "Word A".equals(it) }
def isBlockEnd = { "Word D".equals(it) }

def isInsideBlock = false;    

inputText.eachLine {
    if (!isInsideBlock && isBlockStart(it)) { isInsideBlock = true }
    if (isInsideBlock) println(it)
    if (isInsideBlock && isBlockEnd(it)) { isInsideBlock = false }
}
```

You can [try it here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5162854122520576).

Note that I haven't got much experience with Groovy, I'm sure I'm missing a lot of groovyisms that would make the code shorter / more appreciable to someone with more Groovy experience. But it works, and I don't think you can do much more efficient.